# passing on to classes in mouseover function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I would like to activate the mouseover when there one of the two classes present. Right now I have one class named first-game.

```
 $(document).on('mouseover', 'a.first-game', function(e){
```

Now I want two classes. I tried something like this:

```
 $(document).on('mouseover', 'a.first-game' || 'a.second-game', function(e){
```

Any help would be much appreciated

Comment: The jQuery documentation provides a list with all selectors: http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/. It's worth to have a look at it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use [multiple selector](http://api.jquery.com/multiple-selector/) where each selector is separated by `,`

```
$(document).on('mouseover', 'a.first-game, a.second-game', function(e){
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/jvA9k/)